# /commentThreads endpoint returns no data when the allThreadsRelatedToChannelId parameter is used

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id%2Csnippet&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UC1WYtW_z8Ib49-up6_ltsYA&maxResults=10&pageToken=&searchTerms=&key=You key
```

`/commentThreads` /  `allThreadsRelatedToChannelId`

Google Youtube API for commentThreads does not return any data today afternoon. Does anyone know what the issue is?
[It used to have data like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phECp.jpg), how ever I copied the same request and resend again today, [It shows no value at all][2]

I check my ratelimit, and it is not exceeded. Does any one have the same issue here?

(Edit: The issue was also reported on the [google bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7636), but Google documentation indicates that Stack Overflow is to be used for support questions.  This definitely affects more than a few people)

Comment: Hi Guys Google Youtube API for commentThreads does not return any data today afternoon . Any one know what the issue ? It used to have data like this [How ever I copied the same request and resend again today,It shows no value at all][2]

I check my rate ,and it not excessed . Does any one have the same issue here ?

Comment: I can confirm this.  The `/commentThreads` endpoint briefly stopped returning results when used with the the `allThreadsRelatedToChannelId` parameter on October 9th, went back to normal again, and then stopped working completely on October 12th.  Since this is the only efficient way if to get the most recent comments on a channel with many videos, this is extremely annoying if you want to notify your users about updates.

Comment: Also channelID with searchTerm combination not working as well.

Comment: There is an issue in google issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7636

Comment: The issue has been fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's already reported as issue to Google:
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7636
You can star it and wait for notification.

Comment: The most recent issue in that bugtracker not marked 'New' dates from July this year.  Google also points out that support is done through Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also channelID with searchTerm combination not working as well.

Comment: The issue has been fixed,