# YouTube API returning 0 results for commentThreads call using allThreadsRelatedToChannelId field

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

Using the `googleapiclient` in Python, when I call `commentThreads().list(...)`  with the `allThreadsRelatedToChannelId` parameter filled in (along with the other necessary ones), I get an empty response.  My same API key gets the expected results when instead using a `videoId`.

It looks there was similar behavior reported in October 2015 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092029/commentthreads-endpoint-returns-no-data-when-the-allthreadsrelatedtochannelid-p).

I first encountered this problem running the following call in Python (using the googleapiclient):

```
ct = youtube.commentThreads()
request = ct.list(
    part="id,snippet,replies",
    order="time",
    allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=channel_id,
    maxResults=100,
    textFormat="plainText",
    pageToken=nextpagetoken,
)
response = request.execute()
```

where `youtube` is the API object returned by `googleapiclient.discover.build` with a valid API key passed in. The `channelId` corresponds to the [CrunchLabs](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC513PdAP2-jWkJunTh5kXRw) YouTube channel.  In past weeks, this returned an object with many comment items. Currently the response dictionary is returned with the value `response["pageInfo"] = {"totalResults": 0, "resultsPerPage": 100}`.

I followed up by using the `commentThreads` endpoint in my browser. The url I used is

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id,snippet,replies&order=time&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UC513PdAP2-jWkJunTh5kXRw&maxResults=100&textFormat=plainText&pageToken=&key={API_KEY}&alt=json`

And this returned the same empty response:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
  "etag": "W76_mUzYlAzMZyNF2HoHowz16Tk",
  "nextPageToken": "c3R1ZGlvLS1DZ2dJZ0FRVkY3ZlJPQmdBTW0wS0FpZ0JFbWREYVRoM1RFUkZNMDFFVFROUFJGbDRUMFJuTWs1NlZYbE9hbXR6U1d4V2JtUXdWakJpVjFaTldURmpOR1JHUlRSalZGb3dZbXR2TUZGWFJrSlJhMFp1U1doSllWWlhaRE5TV0ZKMFdsVjRhbFo2YURCVlZHaDRUbTVTZFZOcVVrSlpWVVpEVVZkag==",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 100
  },
  "items": []
}
```

The same Python script was successfully extracting channel comments in the past weeks, and when I use a  `videoId` there is no problem. Is there something I am missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem btw, looks like it's a problem from youtube api, I guess we gotta wait for them to solve it?

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me! For the time being I am trying out a work-around by converting the channelId to a playlistId (replace first two characters 'UC' with 'UU') and looping through the videoIds returned by playlistItems().list(...).

Comment: No, it's not just you. For me (and I'm just guessing you) it's even keeps pumping out `nextPageToken`, so it's a never-ending stream of 0 results, which will eventually fill your quota. Started around 2024-01-03 10:30 UTC give or take half a day or so. Voted up.

Comment: It may help to know that the same thing happens (for me anyway) via "Try this Method" box in the API documentation, per example targeting their developer's channel ID and not in association with a specific API key.

Comment: Reported to google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/318802109


They responded with:


`"Hi, thanks for reporting this issue with us! We have reported this internally and the team is looking into it. Will reach back with updates as soon as we have one."`

Comment: Seems to be back up.